# How to secure an AJAX call from a facebook canvas application

Tags: ajax, facebook

Reading this Ajax example,

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS/Examples/Ajax#Working_Example

I found the following line. I'm not sure what to understand out of it, how do you "check the sig values per Platform spec"?

"Note: For brevity's sake we are trusting $_POST['fb_sig_user'] without checking the full signature. This is unsafe as anyone could easily forge a user's action. Always be sure to either use the Facebook object which is supplied with the client libraries, or check the sig values per Platform spec"

Answer (score 0):

You are under facebook application platform, if there is any leak in security, it is the fault of their platform, API. In other words, you are aleady safe there.

Comment: Hello Sarfraz, Thanks for the reply. What i'm concerned about is, on the server side, where MY application resides. Aside from looking at the fb_sig_user values, there is'nt much i'm doing to make sure that these request are facebook authentic. What should i be doing.